# HBase multithreading client performance

Tags: multithreading, hbase, ipc

We use hbase 1.2.4 in pseudo-destributed mode and java api to read information. Our client makes 20k rps to hbase, but it loads only 30% of cpu and computation takes about 5 hours. I tried to split data and run 4 clients on same machine in separate jvm and had 80k rps with computation time of approximately one hour. This is not the solution to satisfy me. Profiling has shown many blocking of connection threads. 
I have also tried to use ipc pool options of hbase client, but it had not improved performance too much.
If anyone had some similar propblem, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Setting connection pool size much larger then count of reading threads did the trick.

```
Configuration conf;
...
String poolSize = "128";
conf.set(HConstants.HBASE_CLIENT_IPC_POOL_SIZE, poolSize);
conf.set(HConstants.HBASE_CLIENT_IPC_POOL_TYPE, "RoundRobin");
...
Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
...
```